# Is get_headers() function overloading my Apache server?

Tags: php, apache, get-headers

```
$url = "https://www.sportsdirect.com/york-monks-cross-store-1099";
$context = stream_context_create( [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ]);
        
$headers = get_headers($url, 0, $context);
```

This piece of code is overloading my Apache sever and my other websites that are hosted in the same server “does not work”, I mean other websites are loading forever until browser says ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT while the above PHP script is running.

Can anyone explain or suggest me an alternative.

Comment: Maybe the above script throws errors, but the phrase ["does not work" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Other websites hosted on same server loads for long time until browser time out when the above script is running.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.